# Permutation group implementation in Java

Tags: java, permutation, symmetry

In my experience in programming, I often face with different tasks related to permutation group: enumerate all possible products of given permutations or just count them, test whether one permutation can be represented as a combination of given ones, find a subgroup in a given group etc. I suppose that these problems are classic of a computer science and arise in various fields of programming. Currently, in our project we use our own primitive implementation of `PermutationGroup` based on a simplest version of Schreier-Sims algorithm, but it is very limited. I know about various C++ and Python libraries, but is there any Java library which have an efficient implementation of `PermutationGroup` and related topics?

Thanks, Stanislav.

Comment: I wonder what they are programming in Russia.

Comment: I'm surprised at the lack of library support for this in Java. Here's a library that may be helpful: https://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/ Its primary purpose is for generating permutations, but if you convert the output into standard Collection classes, you could use contains on it. I doubt this will be efficient, but it should be easier to maintain.

Comment: This may be a better fit: https://github.com/denisrosset/alasc  It's scala, but you should be able to use the binaries

Comment: @tieTYT Thanks! Unfortunately, the typical number of permutations in group in our work is about 10! - so collections are not a solution.     I've seen AlaSc, but I'm trying to find something in pure Java (best if it published Maven)...

Comment: Out of curiosity - what's the application for this?

Comment: The typical task looks as follows. Suppose you have an array of elements [a,b,c,d,e] and you allowed to swap 1st and 3rd element (1 - 3), a pair of [1st, 2nd] and [4th, 5th] (1,2 - 4,5) etc. If you now have e.g. [c,e,d,a,b] - the question is can you obtain this array by swapping the initial array with the use of allowed swaps? This is a typical subtask of many graph algorithms etc. It used for problems like Card shuffling, design a network of processors for parallel computations and many more. See applications in e.g. D.Holt, Handbook of Computational Group Theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is implementation of `PermutationGroup` and related algorithms in Java in [Redberry](http://redberry.cc) computer algebra system (which is available from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccc.redberry%7Ccore%7C1.1.6%7Cjar) as `cc.redberry.core`). It includes basic algorithms for representing permutation groups in computer (based on [base and strong generating set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_generating_set) and [Schreier-Sims algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier%E2%80%93Sims_algorithm)) and backtrack search algorithms for some types of subgroups (set stabilizers, centralizers etc.). The implementation provides all requested features: enumerating group elements, membership testing, calculation of group order (total number of permutations) and many more.

The following example taken from Redbery [JavaDoc page](http://api.redberry.cc/redberry/1.1.7/java-api/cc/redberry/core/groups/permutations/PermutationGroup.html) highlights some `PermutationGroup` functionality:

```
//permutation in cycle notation
Permutation p1 = Permutations.createPermutation(new int[][]{{0, 9, 3}, {5, 8, 6}, {7, 11, 12}});
//permutation in one-line notation
Permutation p2 = Permutations.createPermutation(2, 0, 1, 8, 3, 5, 7, 11, 4, 12, 9, 6, 10);
//Construct permutation group
PermutationGroup pg = PermutationGroup.createPermutationGroup(p1, p2);
//this group is transitive
assert pg.isTransitive();
//its order = 5616
System.out.println(pg.order());
//Create alternating group Alt(13)
PermutationGroup alt13 = PermutationGroup.alternatingGroup(13);
//its order = 3113510400
System.out.println(alt13.order());
assert alt13.containsSubgroup(pg);
//Direct product of two groups
PermutationGroup pp = pg.directProduct(PermutationGroup.symmetricGroup(8));
//Setwise stabilizer
PermutationGroup sw = pp.setwiseStabilizer(1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11, 12, 3, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18);
assert pp.containsSubgroup(sw);
//its order = 17280
System.out.println(sw.order());
//Center of this stabilizer
PermutationGroup center = sw.center();
//it is abelian group
assert center.isAbelian();
//generators of center
//[+{}, +{{19, 20}}, +{{2, 10}, {3, 9}, {6, 8}, {11, 12}}]
System.out.println(center.generators());
```

More about `PermutationGroup` functionality can be found at [Redberry JavaDoc page](http://api.redberry.cc/redberry/1.1.7/java-api/cc/redberry/core/groups/permutations/package-summary.html).

There is also a nice Groovy interface to Java classes, examples can be found [here](http://redberry.cc/documentation:ref:permutationgroup).

Answer (score 1):

Guava's [Collections2](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html) have zero-memory implementaion of permutations collections. So you can apply basic collection methods on them or Guava's additional operations in `Collections2` and `Iterables`.

> - `orderedPermutations(Iterable)` - Returns a Collection of all the permutations of the specified Iterable using the specified Comparator for establishing the lexicographical ordering. *Notes*: This is an implementation of the algorithm for Lexicographical Permutations Generation, described in Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming", Volume 4, Chapter 7, Section 7.2.1.2. The iteration order follows the lexicographical order. This means that the first permutation will be in ascending order, and the last will be in descending order.
> - `permutations(Collection)` - Returns a Collection of all the permutations of the specified Collection. *Notes*: This is an implementation of the Plain Changes algorithm for permutations generation, described in Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming", Volume 4, Chapter 7, Section 7.2.1.2.

Comment: Had a look at 'Schreier–Sims', okay, that's not what you're looking for.